# Reprojecting from EPSG:3857 to EPSG:28992

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, geopandas, epsg

I'm attempting to reproject a coordinate in EPSG:3857 to EPSG:28992. The problem I'm running into is as follows:

When I use GeoPandas (ie. `df.to_crs(epsg=28992)`) to reproject my coordinates I get a value similar to this for my coordinate: (-587791.60, -5732776.63)

But when I go to the same coordinates (manually) in QGIS (with CRS set to 28992), and right click to get coordinates, the coordinates provided (in CRS 28992) are similar to this: (172839.93,442692.96)

How can I reproject in GeoPandas (or in any other Python library) to get (172839.93,442692.96) instead of (-587791.60, -5732776.63).

When converting a Polygon in GeoPandas and putting it into QGIS all measure of distance is lost (ie, a polygon that was a few km2, becomes a few mm2), but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've been googling for a few hours and I think it might have something to do with how the Datum is transformed, but I'm not sure what exactly that is nor how I can do it properly.

When I change the CRS to 28992 (I drag in OpenStreetMaps), I get the following prompt, which might have something to do with why the coordinates in QGIS are different from GeoPandas (again supporting my Datum transformation theory):[image]

Comment: Hi, Hard to know where the error is with the information provided. Please share the code, sample tables, and/or anything needed to reproduce the issue. Datum transformations can cause shifts, but usually very small ones. Generally half a meter, a few meters in some cases, more than 10 meters in very particular cases.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I think I managed to solve the problem by converting from EPSG:4326 instead of 3857, since my understanding is that 4326 is a "flattened" version of 3857.

Comment: RDnew(-587791.60, -5732776.63) is near 0°E, 0°N, it looks like you have mixed up coordinates. Please add your own solution to your question  as an answer for other Gisstack readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by converting from EPSG:4326 instead of from EPSG:3857.

My understanding is that EPSG:4326 is a "flattened/map" version of EPSG:3857, so they are equivalent.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: EPSG::4326 is a geographic 2D CRS while EPSG::3857 is a projected CRS that uses Mercator for the projection to a plane. Many GIS/map software display 4326 as a rectangle because they don't support showing it as an ellipsoid and/or to match other data.